# 4x"は" as Contrast Marker

Tags: particle-は

Is the following sentence O.K.?

> そのようなブラシ付モーターが、
> 高い回転数領域では、確かに、優れた出力性能は発揮しますが、
> 惜しい事に、定常作動に於いては、結局、十分な静的性能は発揮しないという結果となります。

I am using for times "は" as contrast marker to indicate two contrasts.

> 1. Contrast: 高い回転数領域では versus 定常作動に於いては
> 2. Contrast: 優れた出力性能は発揮します versus 十分な静的性能は発揮しない

Is such a sentence construction possible?

Greetings,

Kenny

Comment: I think そのようなブラシ付モーターは is more natural.

Answer (score 2):

As for 1. Contrast: 高い回転数領域で**は** versus 定常作動に於いて**は**, I think you're correct.

As for 2. 優れた出力性能は発揮します versus 十分な静的性能は発揮しない, I think the は is used to contrast **出力**性能 versus **静的**性能.

I think it might also be fine if it was 優れた出力性能**を**発揮します.

In 十分な静的性能**は**発揮しない, the は also marks the scope of negation. This is partial negation (部分否定), where 十分(な) is negated: "not ~~ enough/fully ~~".

So.. to answer your question "Is such a sentence construction possible?", I'd say yes.